# XAML WPF item selection in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm debugging a code made by a former employee at the company I am working as an intern.

Turns out a DataGrid is not selecting items. Everytime I try to access `DataGrid.SelectedItem` it returns me `null`, even though one row is selected.

[As you can see in this print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqRwU.png)

Follows the XAML code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="SchedulesDataGrid"
                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                  Margin="0 10 0 0"
                                  AlternatingRowBackground="LightSteelBlue"
                                  CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                                  CanUserSortColumns="False"
                                  CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                                  CanUserResizeRows="False"
                                  SelectionMode="Single"
                                  SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
                                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"                                 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding AssemblySchedules, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                                    Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                    IsReadOnly="False"
                                                    Width="200">
                                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                </DataGridTextColumn>

                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type"
                                                        Width="150">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ScheduleType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedScheduleType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                      x:Name="ScheduleTypeComboBox"
                                                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Category"
                                                        Width="150">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                      x:Name="ScheduleCategoryComboBox"
                                                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="View template"
                                                        Width="250">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ScheduleTemplates, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedScheduleTemplate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                      x:Name="ScheduleTemplateComboBox"
                                                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Phase"
                                                        Width="150">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Phases, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPhase, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                      x:Name="SchedulePhase"
                                                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

Am I missing something?

I read throughout the internet that a PropertyChanged binding is necessary but I believe it is already done the right way.

[DataGrid print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3elEp.png)

Can it possibly be because I have to click over the Name in the row, therefore the SelectedItem is not "triggered"?

Comment: Do you need to set the DataGrid's SelectedItem binding, e.g. `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"`? This post is not an exact match to your issue but it may help you, [WPF DataGrid SelectedItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109103/wpf-datagrid-selecteditem)

Comment: I've tried it already tho. Unfortunately didn't work for me. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so basically I had to change some things.

Don't know why and how the selection part of my data grid stopped working. So I created another column to it and added a remove button to each row of the data grid.

To get the row I used inside the button On_Click method `(sender as Button).DataContext` and removing it from the data grid source list.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I initialized my Data Grid

```
        <DataGrid MaxHeight="450" 
                  CanUserAddRows="False" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedResult}">
```

Then in the ViewModel I have this

```
    private Data selectedResult;

    public Data SelectedResult
    {
        get { return selectedResult; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedResult != value)
            {
                selectedResult = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedResult));
            }
        }
    }
```

Data Being the model for the DataGrid Columns

Comment: Didn't word ;-;

I actually thought this selection part was kinda automatic for DataGrid.

Even though it didn't work.

Comment: I think I wasn't detailed enough in my answer, I used a Selection box and when the selection box was a specific value named (Selected Action) which was a button I populated strings with the Selected Result value example             if (SelectedAction.Equals("go"))
            {
                string go = SelectedResult.datacolumn1;
                string gogo = SelectedResult.datacolumn2;}

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. But first, can you see the update I made at my question? Trying what you proposed would take a long time and I think its probably a simple bug (note that it was working perfectly before... maybe some kind of update at the wpf itself caused it, dunno)